Same insert statement on linked server, different behaviours
I have an insert statement basically something like this:
insert into openquery(Test_LinkedServer, 
                      'select a,b,c from my_ora_table')
    select a, b, c 
    from my_dbo_table;

When I execute it, it runs and console returns "xx rows affected" message.
When I try to execute it for the second time, without changing anything, I get an "OLE DB provider" error:

Supplied inconsistent metadata. an extra column was supplied during execution that was not found at compile time

If I add an extra space to the SQL statement in OPENQUERY:
insert into openquery(Test_LinkedServer, 
                      'select a,b(extra_space),c from my_ora_table')

it works for 1 time again.
Does it have some sort of security measure which blocks executing same parsed SQL more than once?

Source database: SQL Server

SQL client: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Target database: Oracle


My linked server provider:

OraOLEDB.Oracle

My linked server properties:

allow inprocess
nested queries


which RDBMS are you using? MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,..... . tag it correctly

sql-server is tagged already, am I missing something?

It wasn't me, moderator added it. if you have a helpful answer please share, otherwise do not spam.

Did you try using your favourite search engine to look for pages mentioning the error message?

I've note that oracle can be kinda buggy. Does: insert into linkedserver.db.schema.tablename (a,b,c)select a,b,c from localtable works

@siggemannen unfortunatelly it acts the same no matter what approach do I try. I’ve tried dynamic sql, openquery and [linkedserver]..[schema].[table] and also your suggestion.

See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/275605/linked-server-throws-metadata-error . Perhaps you can use OPTION(RECOMPILE) or fix the new driver version

yes i did try recompile too but somehow it takes ages to complete execution plan with that option.. thanks anyway:/

There was a driver fix too you could use

not exactly an answer but here is my super nasty workaround, at least for the time being:
the issue occurs when your query being parsed for execution. if it's the first time, it succeed. if you are to re-execute it right after, it fails.
so I added a dummy comment line and replace it with some random number on the runtime. it messes first meta data, because the string is changed.
declare @i nvarchar(max);
declare @s nvarchar(max);

set @i = '
insert into openquery(Test_LinkedServer, 
                      ''select a,b,c /*pseudo_placeholder*/ from my_ora_table'')';
set @s = '
    select a, b, c 
    from my_dbo_table';


begin
set @i = replace(@i, 'pseudo_placeholder', floor(1+(500-1+1)*rand()));
end

exec (@i+@s);

now it can be executed consecutively.
